# Make http POST request that return xml response and parsing XML fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to make a http POST request that parse XML response and return the value of SessionId field that is inside XML. This is what I tried so far.
Ps: is there a way I can run this class from the console, in the way that I can see the response?

```
class Documents::CreateSession

  def initialize()
      @username = Rails.secrets.legal_doc.username
      @password= Rails.secrets.legal_doc.password
  end

  def start

    require "net/http"
    require "uri"

    uri = URI.parse("http://example.com/search")

    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
    request.set_form_data({"userid" => @username, "password" => @password})

    response = http.request(request)

  end

end
```

Comment: What have you tried so far in terms of parsing the XML? The code you've provided is essentially just making an HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can run your code the way that you have it now.  Start a console and do the following:

```
obj = Documents::CreateSession.new
obj.start
```

For debugging purposes, you could put a binding.pry in the start method before you make your request.

Comment: Your example is real basic so I'm not sure what you are after.  I like dumb controllers that can use services and can easily be tested from a console.  This is a good article, but there are many https://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-service-objects-tutorial .